# how to implement a eclipse plugin with autocomplete features

Tags: eclipse, plugins, autocomplete

I want to develop a eclipse plugin for a launguage with auto completion features.

But i don't know where to start. Is there any tutorial on this kind of subject?

Do i need to develop a parser which parses the code first and/or other things?

best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tutorial regarding the development of a custom Eclipse editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786884/tutorial-regarding-the-development-of-a-custom-eclipse-editor)